# Alternatives to scipy.interpolate.griddata that don't hang on aligned points

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have a point dataset that I'm trying to interpolate on a grid.  These points are aligned in grid fashion with some points missing see below: [image]

To complicate it, it's possible that other input pointsets may not align on a grid, so I'm trying to use `scipy.interpolate.griddata` to interpolate these values onto a regular grid.  However, sometimes my underlying grid aligns perfectly with the sampling rate of the input point dataset and `griddata` hangs.  According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5623980/42897) `scipy.interpolate.griddata` operates poorly if the sample occurs across 3 points that are perfectly aligned which sometimes happens for me.

Is there a high performance alternative for interpolation of point data onto a regular grid in Python?

Comment: Do you have multiple data sets, that you combine, and then interpolate? If so, combine them in such a way that points are `not repeated`, this should avoid the problem.

Comment: No it's just a dataset like the one above.  I don't think the problem is that the points are repeated (they're not) but that the sample point may lie directly on the x or y axis and align perfectly with 3 other points, thus causing the Delauney triangulation to barf.

Comment: You could try the current development version of Scipy, which includes a number of bugfixes in `griddata`. A new Scipy version is coming out next month including these fixes, so if you are able to test it already, that would be valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution has been to stochastically perturb the x and y coordinates of each input point by a random factor between `1e-6 * grid_cell_size`.  I choose `1e-6` as a rule of thumb of several orders of magnitude greater than the minimum delta difference in a 32 bit float, yet small enough that the error introduced by it is still shadowed by the error introduced by the interpolation scheme.

I'm still open to other ideas, but this way I can use the stock interpolation functions provided by `scipy` by introducing a very small numerical error.